# Silverlight 4 Problem with Out of Browser sllauncher.exe - no paramaters in shortcut

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My OOB app was working fine. I stupidly renamed all my namespaces and my project names/filenames. (Eventually) I got it all working again but my OOB shortcut stopped working. I removed and reinstalled it but it will not load and throws an error (see below).

It creates the shortcut on my desktop, but if you look at the Target of the shortcut (right-click, properties) it is "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe". I installed some other apps and they have the ApplicationID and the source website in the shortcut (e.g. "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" 3143398843.www.microsoft.com).

Hence, when I click on it, it gives me an error like "Usage: sllauncher.exe xyz".

After some googling, it seems as though the .xap and directory under local settings is being created correctly and the .xap and meta data look fine:
C:\Documents and Settings\Rod\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Silverlight\OutOfBrowser\1457003494.localhost

When it is creating the shortcut it is just not putting the ApplicationID into it - I have turned off and turned on OOB support, restarted my PC etc. but I cannot get it to work.

After one such attempt, it inserted a whole lot of gibberish:
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" ⇴콅䢯㎣鱎㉝眾˚㯘䉘ᇟ薧∀녟፻粨⇴콅䢯㎣鱎㉝眾˚㯘䉘ᇟ薧∀녟፻

Which also failed...

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like I have possibly found a bug in the VS2010 editor: Basically my Application Description under the OOB settings was too long. If I make it shorter than the application link works again (it sounds weird but I tested it extensively and it is definitely that).

To confirm - open your OOB settings and paste a whole lot of text into Application Description. Then try and install it locally (I am keen to know if it is just me/my pc).

Comment: It seems to be a character limit of 260 - I raised the problem on the Silverlight forums and have more info here - http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/190194/440787.aspx#440787